# 125kHz RFID and NFC simultaneously

Tags: rfid, nfc

It it possible to have a passive NFC tag and a 125kHz RFID tag back to back in the same holder and not have one interfere with each other, reading one at a time? E.g Detect 125khz RFID tag, read it, disable 125khz reader, read NFC tag and then disable NFC reader, re-enable the 125KHz reader.

If this is possible, can both readers be active, reading their corresponding tag simultaneously?

For what application this would be used I'm not sure. I'm simply curious about whether or not this is possible.

Comment: I'm unsure what the difference is electrically between the two - are they both 125kHz devices?

Comment: @Andyaka NFC is 13.56MHz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, NFC tech operates within the 13.56Mhz band. 125Khz and 13.56Mhz are far enough apart that there should be no problem with both readers active at the same time, as long as your code can handle it. An NFC reader reads only tags operating within its frequency range and the same goes for the 125kHz reader. So each reader will operate without interfering with each other.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upote, but I don't have enough reputation yet. are there any requirements for antenna placement? I.e. Are they allowed to be stacked, or should they be next to each other?